# select specific input element in a specific row and column

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors

Cosider this image:
[image]

How I can select it without it's ID with jQuery? I mean how I can select it like this statement:

*Find Input in Row with Code=1000 and Column Desc2*

thanks

**Edit 1)**

HTML Code

```
<table border="1" width="300px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Desc2
        </td>
        <td>
            Desc1
        </td>
        <td>
            Code
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#CCCCB3">
            <input id="Text1" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            1000
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#CCCCB3">
            <input id="Text2" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            1001
        </td>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#CCCCB3" class="style1">
                <input id="Text3" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td class="style1">
            </td>
            <td class="style1">
                1002
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#CCCCB3">
                <input id="Text4" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                1003
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you posted the html for your example instead of an image. And is that the whole table or just part of it? I mean if there's only one input field per row, it's trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the last cell, filter the row whose last cell has a value which is equal to "1000", and select the first input element of the collection:

```
$("table td:last-of-type").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "1000";
}).parent().find("input:first");
```

For constructing such selectors, you can use the following:

- [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) and [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq)
- `:nth-child()` (for a specific child position only!)

Warning: Do **not** fall in the trap of `contains()`. This method select all elements which contain the given phrase. `.contains(1000)` will also select `<td>10000</td>`.

Comment: Thanks.I add your code in my page but it does not work.I use this code: `var a = $("table td:last-of-type").filter(function () {
                return $(this).text() == "1000";
            }).parent().find("input:first");
            $(a).text("nima"); `. what is `last-of-type`?

Comment: `td:last-of-type` is a CSS selector which selects every `<td>` element which is the last of its type, with respect to its parent. Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Your code contains spaces. Use `$.trim` to remove beginning and trailing spaces. Also, my code already returns a jQuery object, so there's no need to wrap it in another jQuery object. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qyFk/5/

Comment: thanks it works but it need `$` for get `attr` of it ;).I want a general way to do this.`last-of-type` is a limited solution for this.If my input is in `Desc2` column how I can Select that?

Comment: please help me How I can select a cell according row and column?

Comment: Example: Select row 5, cell 2: `$("table > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(2)")`.